# How to fix Microsoft JScript runtime error '800a1391' is undefined

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlpcQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5H5p.png)

hello everybody, I have a code but when I run, it showed error "Microsoft JScript runtime error '800a1391'

'productId' is undefined

/website/admin_product_details.asp, line 200" but I do not fix this, I use ASP JavaScript, everybody can help me please???

Comment: don't link to images, copy the code here instead.

Comment: @MarkusDresch https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5H5p.png this is link to images code and images error https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlpcQ.png

Comment: @JaromandaX https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5H5p.png this is link to images code and images error https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlpcQ.png

Comment: @JaromandaX, actually he is using ASP/JScript (yes, that old beast). So in fact `<%=productId%>` IS the relevant part. doesn't change the fact that it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Oops. I should've looked at the images properly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: productId is undefined.

`<%=productId%>` is used in line 200 in the asp page, but as the error states, it's not defined anywhere.

You need to define the variable `productId` before using it.